# Delete row if no cells in the entire row are numeric

Tags: vba

I'm looking for a way to delete a row if it contains only text/blank cells.
I have a worksheet with product codes (alphanumeric), descriptions (text), and quantities (numeric) in various columns (not consistent between sheets). I'm trying to find a way to delete rows with no product quantities as they don't need to be entered into the system. I'm not really sure how to approach the problem, I'm still pretty new to vba

```
Dim nums As Boolean
  For Each myRow In Range("A1:P200")
    nums = True
    For Each myCell In myRow
      If IsNumeric = False Then
        Set nums = False
        If nums = False Then
          Rows.EntireRow.Delete
```

Is my attempt so far, it doesn't like the if statements. Also I need to keep rows with a numeric cell and many blank cells, will this not delete any rows with some blank cells?

Comment: Dim nums As Boolean, For Each myRow In Range("A1:P200"), nums=True. For Each myCell In myRow, If Isnumeric=False, Set nums=False. If nums=False, Rows.EntireRow.Delete.  Is my attempt so far, it doesn't like the if statements. Also I need to keep rows with a numeric cell and many blank cells, will this not delete any rows with some blank cells? (sorry about formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to start:

- declare a boolean value
- make a for each loop like this:

---

```
For each myRow in Range("A1:Z100").Rows
```

---

- set the boolean value to `True`
- make a new loop like this:

---

```
For each myCell in myRow
```

---

- check each cell whether it is `Numeric`. If it is not, set the boolean value to `False`.
- at the end of the inner loop delete the row if the boolean value is `True`.